# An isomorphism between $( \mathbb{R} , + )$ and $ ( P , \cdot )$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Am I incorrect in believing that the following exercise is not possible?

> Prove that the additive group $( \mathbb{R}, + )$ of real numbers is isomorphic to the multiplicative group $( P , \cdot )$ of positive reals.

My reasoning is that if we had $\phi \colon \mathbb{R} \to P$ as our isomorphism, then we have

$$\phi(\tfrac{1}{3}) = \tfrac{1}{3}$$ 
and
$$\phi(-3) = \tfrac{1}{3}$$

Am I missing something?

Comment: Why would we have that?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Do we not have to map inverses to inverses? That along with the fact that $\frac{1}{3} \in \mathbb{R}^+$ and $P$.

Comment: Both of those things are true, but they don't imply what you're concluding. If you write out your argument in more detail it should be easier to see the mistake.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Oh, right, *reals*. I've just come off a binge of problems dealing with $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ exclusively. I see my error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Isomorphism between groups of real numbers](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345246/isomorphism-between-groups-of-real-numbers)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your reasoning is a little faulty since you are assuming that $\phi ( \frac{1}{3} ) = \frac 13$ (since *a priori* there is not reason to think that $\frac 13$ must be a fixed point of such an isomorphism). But *even if* $\phi ( \frac 13 ) = \frac 13$, then this would tell us that $$\begin{align}
\phi ( 3 ) 
&=  \phi (\tfrac 13+\tfrac 13+\tfrac 13+\tfrac 13+\tfrac 13+\tfrac 13+\tfrac 13+\tfrac 13+\tfrac 13) \\ 
&= \phi (\tfrac 13)\cdot\phi(\tfrac 13)\cdot\phi(\tfrac 13)\cdot\phi(\tfrac 13)\cdot\phi(\tfrac 13)\cdot\phi (\tfrac 13)\cdot\phi(\tfrac 13)\cdot\phi(\tfrac 13)\cdot\phi(\tfrac 13) \\ 
&= \tfrac 13 \cdot \tfrac 13 \cdot \tfrac 13 \cdot \tfrac 13 \cdot \tfrac 13 \cdot \tfrac 13 \cdot \tfrac 13 \cdot \tfrac 13 \cdot \tfrac 13 \\ 
&= 3^{-9}
\end{align}$$
and therefore $\phi ( -3 ) = ( \phi ( 3 ) )^{-1} = ( 3^{-9} )^{-1} = 3^9$.

---

If you recall the following rule of exponentiation: $$a^{x+y} = a^x \cdot a^y$$ you should begin to think that a mapping of the form $x \mapsto a^x$ looks "homomorphism-ish," and it is not too difficult to show that if $a > 0$, then such a mapping is an isomorphism between $( \mathbb{R} , + )$ and $( P , \cdot )$.